# Symfony + fosuserbundle + security issue with firewalls

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-security

I was having trouble with symfony security + fos user bundle.
I couldn't find anybody that replicated my problem, only similar problems but the solutions are not working.
All the pages including / has to be secured except registration/resetting/login urls.

When I go to /login the url is "protected" unless I add it to my registration firewall. this works until I try to login and then it says I need to add the login path to the main firewall.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    registration:
        pattern: ^/(login|register|resetting)
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:             true
        anonymous:          true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js), role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by limiting the pattern of ^login to ^login$ so that login_check still passes to the main firewall.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false

    registration:
        pattern: ^/(register|resetting)
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider:  security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:             true
        anonymous:          true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js), role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```